# Glide reload content on scrolling in listview

Tags: android, image, android-glide

i'm using glide to load content, i use this to load 1 image in a page and its working good if i close and reopen my app. the problem is when i use it on listview, glide always redownload it.
detail error steps:

1. after load the content from server, all image appear normal
2. then i scroll it down, new content also appear normal
3. when i scroll back, all image is disappear but after 1s my image appear again because glide load it back just like glide never load it before.
4. if i have portrait orientation, the first loaded, it will fill the layout width but the second time (scroll back listview) image appear smaller not full width.

here is my snipped code

```
View view = convertView;
if (null == view) {
    view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.item, null);
}

ImageView ivAvatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
ImageView ivPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_picture);
TextView tvName = ....
...
tvName.setText(.....);  

Glide.with(parent.getContext()).load(Api.getUrlImage(contents.get(position).avatar, 50, 0)).into(ivAvatar);
Glide.with(parent.getContext()).load(Api.getUrlImage(contents.get(position).picture, 400, 0)).into(ivPicture);
```

on point 3, its like a blinking, but the image view lost its height. text below the image going up (like no image view in there) then go back down after glide finish load image
on point 4, my screen resolution is 480px and i load 400px image (resize by server) as seen on second glide code.

> my question, how to remove this blinking image?

*i run this on low-spec device and hi-spec device (samsung tab s) and blinking happen in both device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using dontAnimate() and see if it solves the problem?

If the problem still persists, then it is because that Glide frees the resources of the previous images in order to load the subsequent images.

If you have lots of images to load in a scrolling list and you need to support low-spec device, fresco is a better option. http://frescolib.org/index.html It uses native memory and has a much better bitmap resource management especially for pre-5.0 Android devices.

Comment: i just try implement frescolib, working as needed. just for info, i thought its error on my code about image height until read this http://frescolib.org/docs/wrap-content.html

Answer (score 2):

try to use if before use glide in `onCreateView` method  in your adapter

like this

```
if (yourImageView.getDrawable() == null)
// load your image
```

so if image already loaded the method don't return null

Comment: @NameSurname Welcome bro

Comment: This will leave the previously loaded image, which is gonna be wrong. ViewHolders are reused, u no matter where view holder is and for which data it is used, u gonna only see the first loaded image.

Comment: @Sermilion you can remove an image from view when view Recycled,
show onViewRecycled method